# $W^{k,p}_{0}$ is scale invariant

Tags: lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, real-numbers, smooth-functions, euclidean-domain

I'm trying to prove the following;

> $W^{k,p}_{0} (\Bbb{R^2})$ is scale invariant for the the functional $E[u] = \int_{\Bbb{R}^2} |\delta_tu(0, x)| + |\delta_{xx}u(0, x)| dx $;

I have got the result

> $E[u] = E[u_\lambda]$ where $u_\lambda(t,x) = u(\lambda^{-2}t, \lambda^{-1}x)$ for $\lambda \in (0, \infty)$

I also know that $W^{k,p}_{0}$ functions can be interpreted as the $W^{k,p}$ functions whose derivatives upto the $(k-1)^{th}$ order vanish on the boundary. In this case, $k=2, p=1$ so I must proof that $W^{2,1}_{0}$ is scale invariant. The part I don't get is where exactly the derivative of order 1 vanishes in this case? Here $u$ is a $\Bbb{C}^4(\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R^2})$ solution to the thin plate equation.

Also, how does only lower order derivatives in $W^{k,p}_{0}$ can vanish on boundary but the higher order derivative does not have this boundary vanishing property?

Comment: You might want to include a definition of what "scale invariance" means. It's also not clear what the "for the function E[u]=..." is supposed to mean given that E[u] is just a number.

Comment: $E[u]$is a linear functional which equals to $E[u_\lambda]$ for a scaling family $u_\lambda$ as given in the statement.

Comment: In simpler terms, it means that the value for $E[u]$ does not change for any $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$

Comment: Ah, so E[u] is a *functional*, not a *function*. Then I understand how that functional is scale invariant, but what does it mean for the whole space to be scale invariant?

Comment: That's the part where I'm confused myself.

Comment: Well, you can't prove something if you don't know how it is defined.

Comment: Hey I know what $W^{k,p}_{0} (\Bbb{R^2})$ and how it is defined. Please read the last para in the question. I'm asking about how the first derivative vanished in $E[u]$?

Comment: What I asked was what "W^{k,p}_0 is scale invariant for ..." means. And you said "That's the part where I'm confused myself".